# Python __init__ file can't import modules

Tags: python, import, module, package

I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't get to an answer.

My package folder looks like this, no sub folders, just a flat package folder with .py files in it.

```
+Package
∣
∣--__init__.py
∣--moduleA.py
∣--moduleB.py
```

If I run my test.py script from inside the package folder, the imports, classes and methods work fine:

```
import moduleA.py
import moduleB.py

# ...stuff
```

Now, if I try to run my package from outside importing `import Package`, outside being \site-packages I get

```
File "defaultPathTo\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Package\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import moduleA
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleA'
```

This is my init file

```
import moduleA
import moduleB
```

I tried changing the content to `from moduleA import *`, `from . import moduleA`

`from .moduleA import (whatever class)` seems to work, but I don't want to change all my classes from `moduleA.ClassA` because it clashes with class names from the other modules.

I think I summed up all the information neede. Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to put the package on the path somehow. You can install via `pip` for example for modify `sys.path` to include an entry for that directory.

Comment: site-packages is certainly on sys.path, and `Package` is underneath site-packages, so this likely isn't a path issue.  `moduleA` can't be imported directly; the import needs to import `Package`.

Comment: Is that the "correct" way tough? I've seen that solution but looks invasive and haven't seen that other packages have it @a_guest

Comment: @John Gordon I edited my post, normally I'd `import Package`

Comment: @G-BC "Correct" should be defined by your use case. Installing a package will give you additional benefits such as versioning while modifying `sys.path` is a really quick solution. You can also modify `PYTHONPATH` or [`site.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).

Comment: Can you try and recreate the error on repl.it or somewhere similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `from . import moduleA` for all imports from within my package did the trick.

I may have done something wrong the first time I tried because I got `no known parent folder`